# Why does Outlook 2010 keep forgetting my domain password?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-domain

Every few days, Outlook asks for my password, and I give it and check the "Remember me" box. After a few days - I should maybe not how many; if it's regular or ranmdom - it has forgotten me, and I must repeat the password entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting your profile as default in the mail profile?
You can achieve this by: Control panel > User accounts > Mail > Show profile and then setting yours as default. If it is not in there you can just add it and set as default. Hope this helps.